Double background but only one specified
I'm trying to learn HTML, but I have this problem:

I don't know why, but my background is repeated for no reason... Here is my CSS body (because the problem seems to come with the body), and if I put a huge component at the bot of my card (I'm MisTrale, etc...):


body {
    font-family: Inter, system-ui, Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100vh;
  
    color-scheme: light dark;
    background-image: radial-gradient(at center, #0d1d31 0%, #0c0d13 100%);
  
    font-synthesis: none;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
<div class="group">
    <div class="animated-background"></div>
    <div class="animated-background-solid"></div>
    <div class="size-slot-container">
        <div class="slot-container">
            <div class="intro">
                <p class="greeting">Hey </p>
                <h1 class="name">I'm MisTrale </h1>
                <h2 class="role">FullStack Developer <span style="color: red;">Engineer</span></h2>
                <p class="description">
                    I want to be a <span style="color: red;"> Full-Stack </span> Developer specializing in <span style="color: blue;">front-end</span>, <span style="color: blue;">back-end</span>, and <span style="color: blue;"> mobile </span> development using Flutter. 
                    I am passionate about creating seamless and efficient applications that provide real value. 
                    Actively seeking opportunities to leverage my skills in meaningful projects and contribute to the growth of the tech industry.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="aboutme">
</div>
<style>
    .aboutme {
        height: 900px;
    }
</style>



Thank you guys!

repeat is the default value for background-repeat (which I'm not seeing an entry for). Have you tried adding a rule and setting it to no-repeat?

@j08691 Thank you and sorry for the time to my answer (my connection crashed...) Yeah I tried to do this but now he looks like that: https://pasteboard.co/z5Ik8YaOQYH4.png (I can't paste my image)

@j08691 I want my background to go all the way down without repetition :) (I don't know if it's possible...)

Update I found something, i changed my body with: html, body { Thank you @j08691

There is a CSS3 property for background size, viz background-size.  You can set length values, it's usually used with special values 'contain' and 'cover' as per your requirement.
body {
    background-image:    url(images/background.png);
    background-size:     cover;
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

